# Present participle modifier modifying another present participle modifier

Tags: modifiers, present-participles

***A desecrated B, provoking riots.***

In the aforementioned sentence, " provoking riots" modifies the previous clause.

***A desecrated B, provoking riots, forcing the riot police to intervene***

Here, does the modifier " ***forcing the riots police .....***" aptly modifies the modifier " ***provoking riots***" by offering the result of it?

What I want the sentence to say is that

***A desecrated B .***

***The act of desecration provoked riots which in turn forced the riot police to intervene.***

Comment: No problem with two successively-occurring participials in a row; you could also use _and_ between them, with optional comma. And you could use _thus_ and _therefore_ and various linkers like that, if you want.

Comment: I'd include an 'and', but that's merely style preference. _A desecrated B, provoking riots, and forcing the riot police to intervene_. The role of 'and' is ambiguous. It can mean just 'and in addition'; it can imply sequentiality; it can (as easily deduced here) have the further implication of causality (rioting → intervention by riot police).

Comment: Thanks, John and Edwin